# I can't connect to ethernet in ubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, 15.10

In 14.04 32 bit Ethernet worked fine but after installing 15.10 64 bit it doesn't work. My computer can't use WiFi so I have no internet connection at all.

I have heard people saying to check /etc/network/properties but I can't edit that file I have no permission to do that. I'm missing something in there (i have forgotten the name of it but I think it's another word for Ethernet).

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2` :

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology CO., Ltd Motherboard [1458:e000]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# interfaces (5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 eth` Is the same output as `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2`

edit*

I have now added `auto eth0
    allow-hotplug eth0
    iface eth0 inet dhcp`  to the file called: `/etc/network/interfaces` but still does not work. Is it something else missing in that file?

EDIT*

I found a very good tutorial on youtube that tells you how to set up interfaces and fix your ip-adress. So now I have that symbol in the top right hand corner that indicates that I´m connected with ethernet but I´m only conneceted to my router, not to the rest of the world. Maybe it´s a problem with my dns.

This is how `/etc/resolv.conf` look like:

```
`# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
```

## DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

nameserver 127.0.0.1
search mydomain.local`

I have not changed the file but I have fixed so I now have permission to change it.

Maybe this will help you finding an answer to the problem, when i type `ifconfig` it tells me that `enp3s0 
inet addr:192.168.0.240 Bcast:192.168.0.255 Mask:255.255.255.0`

and `lo      inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0`

So my `/etc/network/interfaces`file looks like this:

```
    # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
adress 192.168.0.240
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

EDIT* 
Internet works fine now when I updated the drivers

Comment: Please post the output of `lspci | grep Ethernet`

Comment: Better `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2`

Comment: Your settings in `/etc/network/interfaces` are wrong. Gateway is not in the same subnet as the interface. It should be `192.168.0.1` or the IP address should be another, etc.

Comment: Now when i startet my computer again I can´t even acces the router. Changig the gateway in `/etc/network/interfaces` did not work.

Comment: 8 mins later connected to router again... so random

Comment: 5 mins later with new drivers works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have any other internet connection. you can install `r8168-dkms` offline.

Download theese files:

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/r8168/r8168-dkms_8.040.00-1_all.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu6_all.deb

You can do it using some other computer. Copy these files to Ubuntu Home folder and run in terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i r8168-dkms_8.040.00-1_all.deb dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu6_all.deb
sudo modprobe -r r8169
sudo modprobe r8168
```

But in your case you just have a wrong config in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: @edwardtorvalds There was a more important error. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay you are using a realtek network card some of the realtek drivers are really bad you are going to have to change driver to make things work.

Do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
```

Now you have to blacklist the old driver, do this by opening the blacklist file and adding the drivername to the bottom of the file on a new line:

```
sudo gedit  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Add: r8169

Then reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

And it should now work.

Comment: Dont´t you need a internet connection to download a new driver?

Comment: When I do `sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms` it says "can not find the package r8168-dkms"

Comment: The package is in the repository if you have problems finding it you can also download it here: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/wily/universe/base/r8168-dkms or use the synaptic package manager too search for it.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I Downloaded r8168-dkms as well as the base dkms package (http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/xenial/main/base/dkms) to a flash drive, installed with `dpkg -i <file>`, blacklisted r8169 and rebooted and my internet works perfectly now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are administrator you should have access to

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

Some more information could be useful here please post the results from running the following commands:

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces

lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 eth
```

Also try to restart networking service and bring eth0 online:

```
sudo service networking restart

sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

Comment: If you have any other information about which ethernet / wireless module you have it can be useful.

Comment: How do you write these fancy letters from the terminal?

Comment: With your keyboard, if you have trouble you can copy and paste them.